# How to define 'interp' when using imwarp

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm using `imwarp` to modify an image like this:

```
WarpedImage=imwarp(Image, tform, 'OutputView', imref2dObject);
```

I would like to define the interpolation parameter called 'interp' listed in [the manual](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imwarp.html):

But this:

```
Interp='nearest';
WarpedImage=imwarp(Image, tform, 'OutputView', imref2dObject, 'Interp', Interp);
```

gives the error:

```
Error using imwarp>parseInputs (line 329)
Argument 'Interp' did not match any valid parameter of the parser.
```

and that:

```
WarpedImage=imwarp(Image, tform, 'OutputView', imref2dObject, Interp);
```

gives:

```
Error using imwarp>parseInputs (line 329)
Parameter 'nearest' does not have a value.
```

What is the correct way of defining this parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical MATLAB function may have 3 kinds of parameters: required, optional, and name-value pairs. Required parameters come first, then optional parameters, and then the name-value pairs.  In the case of `imwarp`, `Image` and `tform` are required, and `interp` is optional, so it has to come before the name-value pairs:

```
WarpedImage=imwarp(Image, tform, Interp, 'OutputView', imref2dObject);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try put `Interp` before the other options (e.g., `'OutputView'`...)

```
>> WarpedImage=imwarp(Image, tform, Interp, 'OutputView', imref2dObject);
```